# How to add button to scrollView and have an event for that using corona sdk?

Tags: lua, scrollview, coronasdk

I am uisng scrollView.lua for scroll but to get back out of it, i need to put back button on that but there is no button action event for scroll view

```
local menuBtn
    local onMenuBtn = function( event )
            if event.phase == "release" then

            print ("I am in onMenuBtn btn action" )

            scrollView:removeSelf(); scrollView = nil
            menuBtn:removeSelf(); menuBtn = nil

            director:changeScene( "slide1" )

            end


        end
        menuBtn = ui.newButton
        {
            defaultSrc = "menubtn.png",
            defaultX = 100,
            defaultY = 42,
            overSrc = "menubtn.png",
            overX = 100,
            overY = 42,
            onEvent = onMenuBtn,
            id = "menuBtn",
            text = "",
            font = "Helvetica",
            textColor = { 255, 255, 255, 255 },
            size = 16,
            emboss = false
        }
        menuBtn.x = 50
        menuBtn.y = 30
        scrollView:insert( menuBtn )
```

Please any one help me

Thank you,
madan mohan

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
local listener

function listener:tap( event )
  onMenuBtn( event )  --or just put your code straight here
end

menuBtn:addEventListener( "tap", listener );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use widget.scrollView() for the purpose of this since it is easier and dont need any other file to include. The following link may help you.

http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/widgetnewscrollview